# Routing to different node.js express-apps on one server

Tags: node.js, express, node.js-connect

I want to run different apps on one server, but the routing between them should be made with *paths* and not with *sub-domains*.

I read about **bouncy** and the **connect vhost middleware**, but they just allow me to route sub-domains to different ports.

I want something like this:

`domain.com` -> app1

`domain.com/api` -> app2, in order that `/api` is `/` for app2

`domain.com/some/path` -> app3, in order that `/some/path` is `/` for app3

The position in the **route tree** should be transparent to the apps and it would be nice if I don't have to restart any other app when adding a new one.

Do I have to code it myself or is there some solution out there?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Assuming each app is running in its own process, you essentially need a reverse proxy.

[http-proxy](https://github.com/nodejitsu/node-http-proxy) is your best bet.  You can mix an Express app and the proxy ("app1"), and forward requests for /api to app2 and /some/path to app3.

app2 and app3 can be running on the same box or different boxes.

---

If this is all happening in the same process, just `use` the `router` from app1 and app2 mounted to a path:

```
var app1=express(), app2=express(), app3=express();

app1.use(app1.router);
app1.use('/api', app2.router);
app1.use('/some/path', app3.router);
```